# Couldn't add Database file in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Yes I know that this question has been asked many times, but this problem seems to be persistent.

I have had this error before but that was during hosting on IIS.For that reason I shifted from VS2013 to VS2010. There is no problem in VS2010, but I need VS2013 and now here I stand where I can't even add a DATABASE FILE.

Now here is the error which I am getting while adding a database :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 – Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details. )

Now I understand there is some error with the SQL Server's version, I tried all that is said within this : http://kbijayanta.azurewebsites.net/tag/localdbv12-0/ link.

What is a definitive solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't copy paste question anyway if you want asnwer

1. Open command prompt
2. Run `SqlLocalDB.exe start v11.0`
3. Run `SqlLocalDB.exe info v11.0`
4. Copy the instance pipe name that starts with np:...
5. In Visual Studio select `Tools > Connect to Database...`
6. For Server Name enter `(localdb)\v11.0`. If it doesn't work, use the instance pipe name that you copied earlier. You can also use this to connect with SQL Server Management Studio.
7. Select the database on next dropdown list
8. Click OK!

Try this

delete and recreate your `LocalDB\v11.0` database! At the command prompt type:

```
sqllocaldb delete v11.0  
sqllocaldb create v11.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied it but I got same error and thanks it worked for me perfectly

1. Open command prompt
2. Run `SqlLocalDB.exe start v11.0`
3. Run `SqlLocalDB.exe info v11.0`
4. Copy the instance pipe name that starts with np:...
5. In Visual Studio select `Tools > Connect to Database...`
6. For Server Name enter `(localdb)\v11.0`. If it doesn't work, use the instance pipe name that you copied earlier. You can also use this to connect with SQL Server Management Studio.
7. Select the database on next dropdown list
8. Click OK!

Comment: @user5117836 bad practice man.. you can't just copy others answer and post it as your answer..

Comment: i was just saying this code worked perfectly sorry i'm new so i don't have many idea and thx for feed back

Comment: ya @TFrost we cant copy and just paste other answer but as we know he/she is new to StackOverFlow he will be familiar in few days